# finding when a string occurs inside a cell in excel

Tags: vbscript, excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of numerical data, all arranged in one column. The data is broken up by the use of a keyword.

```
KEYWORD
1
2
3
4
5
KEYWORD
1
2
KEYWORD
.
.
.
```

I was wondering if there was a way to quickly take the averages between each instance of the keyword, and set it in the cell to the right of the area that was just averaged. I have never done any real hardcore VBA scripting, so I am totally at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.  There may be a better way, though.

```
Sub GetAverages()
    Dim sum As Single
    Dim count As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("a1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        If CStr(cell.Value) = "KEYWORD" Then
            If count > 0 Then
                ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row - 1, cell.Column + 1).Value = sum / count
            End If

            count = 0
            sum = 0
        Else
            sum = sum + cell.Value
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

It outputted this on my sample data...

```
KEYWORD 
92  
20  
93692   
936 
92         18966.4
KEYWORD 
32  
324        178
KEYWORD 
235 
324 
23  
3   
342 
2   
343 
34         163.25
KEYWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use VBA.

Use this formula in column next to the column with values:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(<columnName>);<columnName>;"")
```

For example if you column with values is C then

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C1);C1;"")
```

Then use the `Average` function on the new column:

```
=AVERAGE(D:D)
```